# Help with a custom references style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

So...I'm not the only one who needs to use some custom style in their bibliography. As I'm annoyed with using office word editors I would like to create a tex template that I can use over and over and that will save me a lot of manual editing in the long term.
I'm using biblatex and biber.

Well, I'll come to the guidelines. The cites in the text should be in the format (Surname Year:Page), I figured out this one by searching around the internet and it works, the only thing missing is it should be (Author1/Author2 Year:Page) instead of an "and" between these authors, how do I do this?

Now for the really tricky part, the references.

Books should look like this:
[image]

So after the author there is a newline, then the year and the remaining text should be tabbed in, I have no idea how to do this.

For articles, it should be this: [image]

This is what it currently looks like: [image]

There needs to be a comma after the title, the 19.2 should be 19/2 and I need to get rid of the "S." indicating the pages. I think the symbol showing the page range would also disturb my professor, it should just be a "-".

I really hope someone can help me to get this stuff settled. I already invested hours I could have spent writing my papers and didn't really got anything :<

Edit: After some more hours of research I worked out most of the stuff I needed. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% Schriftumschaltung mit den nativen XeTeX-Anweisungen
                     % vornehmen. Voreinstellung: Latin Modern
\usepackage{polyglossia}% Sprachumschaltung
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Kochi Gothic}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[comma,authoryear]{natbib}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{14.06.2015}
\fancyhead[L]{Name}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}% Voreingestellte Dokumentsprache: Deutsch
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=philosophy-modern,isbn=false,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=2,minbibnames=1]{biblatex}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes} %,german=guillemets
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  references = {Literaturverzeichnis},
  editor = {\mkbibparens{Hg\adddot}} %Hg. statt Hrsg.
}
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{% %Hg. bzw Hgg. in Klammern hinter Herausgeber, statt davor
 \ifnameundef{editor}
 {}
 {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
 \setunit{\addspace}%
 \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
 \clearname{editor}%
 \newunit}%
 \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
 \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{ 
   andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},             
} 
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
%\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}\nopunct}
\DefineBibliographyExtras{german}{\protected\def\bibrangedash{-}}
%\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}
%\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{Available from\addcolon\space\url{#1}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{volume = {}}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addslash}
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}\addperiod} % italic title with period

%\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{publisher}{#1\addcolon}

\begin{filecontents}{tempbib.bib}
@article{oshio,
     title = {The association of life satisfaction and self-rated health with income dynamics among male employees in Japan},
     author = {Oshio, Takashi et al.},
     journal = {Japan and the World Economy},
     volume = {28},
     number = {},
     pages = {143-150},
     year = {2013},
    }

@misc{wikipedia,
author = {Wikipedia},
title = {Einzelwissenschaft},
publisher = Wikipedia,
howpublished = {http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einzelwissenschaft},
note = {Accessed: 14.06.2015}
}

@incollection{X,
  author      = "O. Grandstrand",
  title       = "Innovation and Intellectual Property Rights",
  editor      = "J. Fagerberg",
  booktitle   = "Oxford Handbook of Innovation",
  publisher   = "Oxford University Press",
  address     = "Oxford",
  year        = 2004,
}

@BOOK{AC026465742,
author = {Kurz, Robert},
title = {Schwarzbuch Kapitalismus; ein Abgesang auf die Marktwirtschaft},
year = {1999},
address = {Frankfurt am Main},
publisher = {Eichborn},
ISBN = {3-8218-0491-2}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{tempbib.bib}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Kapitel}
\section{Kapitel}

\parencite[8-10]{oshio}.

\nocite{*}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literaturverzeichnis}\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

[image]

This is what it currently looks like, so far so good. The first entry should have a colon after the (Hg.) and should be followed by the title (Oxford Handbook...), the editor should come directly after the title, as seen here:
[image]

Entry 2 and 3 are perfect, entry 4 should look like this:
[image]
With the URL starting a new line and the date the site was accessed in parens.

When using

```
\parencite
```

with exactly two authors it should be SurnameAuthor1/SurnameAuthor2 instead of the current "SurnameAuthor 1 und SurnameAuthor 2".

And now finally to my last question: is it possible to make the philosophy-modern style use ibidem (respectively it's German equivalent ebd.) when citing the same work multiple times?

Comment: At first sight this seems quite similar to what [`biblatex-philsophy`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-philosophy)'s `philosophy-modern` style does. Could you try that style and identify the point that need changing?

Comment: Of course the separator between `volume` and `number` as well as the page format would still need ton be changed, but there is help for that round here. Have a look [at this for the `volume/ `number` issue](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/81569/35864) and [here for the `pages` thing (it is quite long answer, search for "pages")](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13076/35864).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The philosophy-modern style indeed is much closer to my desired end result, however there is still some finetuning needed. It currently looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/yi4Lb8y.png

There should be a period after the title in the first entry and a colon between the location and publisher, so "[...] Abgesang auf die Marktwirtschaft. Eichborn: Frankfurt am Main."

I got rid of the pages thing thanks to your link in the second entry. There should be no comma between the Journal and the Volume, only the Journal needs to be in italics

Comment: Also: is it possible to get the dash into a different format? It seems to be a --, but it should be a -

Comment: Alright, got the period after the title with
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}\addperiod}
but I can't figure out how to use DeclareFieldFormat for the address/location field...

Comment: Since you have not received an answer yet, I would think it legitimate to update the question with what you have so far (`philsophy-modern` and your modifications) preferably with a fully working [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) (not just bits if code) and make focus your question on what exactly is missing.

Comment: BTW `biblatex-philsophy` as a very, very extensive set of options that do not exist in standard `biblatex`. Maybe some of those are helpful.

Comment: I updated my question and added a MWE.