# Bibliography: Special Formatting

Tags: bibliographies, formatting

*A friend asked me for help...*

**Problem**

Given a document class like `book`.

Consider the package `biblatex` calling the option `backend=bibtex`.

(My `.bib`-file is written in bibtex format i.e. `@article{...}`.)

Is it possible to have the bibliography as follows:

> Family Name, Initials. (Year). Title. *Journal*, *Volume*(Number), Pages.

**Examples**

As an example with one aurthor:

> Porter, M. E. (1996). What is strategy? *Harvard Business Review*, *74*(1), 61-78.

As an example with two authors:

> McMullen, J. S. & Shepherd, D. A. (2006). Entrepreneurial action and the role of uncertainty in the theory of the entrepreneur. Academy of Management Review, *31*(1), 132-152.

**Code**

The `.tex`-file looks like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{Bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}
Reference:~\cite{ItemName}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The `.bib`-file looks like:

```
@article{ItemName,
title = {Title},
year = {Year},
journal = {Journal},
author = {Eisenhardt, Kathleen M. and Graebner, Melissa E.},
doi = {10.1098/rspb.2008.0355},
number = {Number},
pages = {Pages},
volume = {Volume},
publisher = {Publisher},
url = {http://www.google.de}
}
```

Comment: Using `style=authoryear` should come pretty close if you additionally have `firstinits=true`. Changing the volume, number format has been done before (quite often I would have thought, take [biblatex: parentheses around the volume number of an article](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/81569/35864) for a start)

Comment: A nice thank you!! What about the italic font of *Journal* and *Volume*?

Comment: Italic font for the `journal` is standard, and for volume can be obtained using `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\mkbibemph{#1}}`. Please read [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864) for a first overview and search this site for the things you need changed if that post didn't help.

Comment: Ah yes that helped alot - thanks!!!

Comment: Does that mean your question is solved? If so, I would like to close it as a duplicate of [biblatex: parentheses around the volume number of an article](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/81569/35864), even though your question had two small other bits about it, would you be OK with that?

Comment: @moewe: Your answer was already pretty good. Thanks also for the links -they both really helped alot!!! And yes we can close this thread as duplicate. :)