# Bibliography layout

Tags: biblatex, texstudio

I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

In the past, I used `biblatex` with Biber (I use Texstudio as a editor and I was told that that was the less problematic way to make a bibliography with Texstudio).

This was the code in my template:

```
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
.
.
.
\printbibliography
```

However, now I need to do something different.
I will provide you an example to avoid misunderstandings.

The references should look like this:

[image]

I wonder also if it is possible to bracket the date (Surname, Name (date))
I had also some problems when there were more than one author. Usually I simply wrote the author in `sth.bib` as "Name et al. Surname" and LaTeX rearranged everything as "Surname, Name et al.". However, it would be nice if I manage to name everyone.

In the body, a reference should look like

lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (Surname date, page)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It sounds like you want the "APA" formatting style. Please confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general style you seem to want is and authir-year style and not a numeric one, so you need `style=authoryear`.

If you use `\autocite` with that style you get citations in brackets (you could of course also use `\parencite`, but `\autocite` is more comfortable if you decide to switch styles later on).

Since you only seem to want first name initials, add the option `giveninits=true`, `maxbibnames=999` will show all authors in the bibliography.
*Never* give a name in the `.bib` file as `Surname, Name et al.`. Always use the format described in [How should I type author names in a bib file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557) and [How to properly write multiple authors in bibtex file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864).

Judging from your screen capture you also want [Suppress “In:” biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864), [biblatex: How to remove the parentheses around the year in authoryear style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12254/35864), [biblatex: parentheses around the volume number of an article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/81569/35864) as well as a few other modifications

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber,giveninits,maxbibnames=999]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings]
  {title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings]
  {citetitle}{#1}

\begin{document}
\autocite[380]{sigfridsson} \autocite[33]{worman}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The link of "How to properly write multiple authors in bibtex file" is not correct, but I have anyhow found the topic.

Comment: @Marco Ah, yes, thanks for the head-up. I have corrected the link.