# Lastname first for first author citation style

Tags: bibliographies, citing

Is there a bibliography style that

1. Reverses first author's first and last name
2. Directly display the journal. Not like:

> In: *The Journal*

3. Order (alphabetical) the references by first author's last name
4. Use "and" instead of comma to list the last author

**An example is the following:**

[image]

Comment: Is biblatex an option?

Comment: Yes, but still don't know how to use biblatex to produce the sample result.

Comment: Biblatex's `authoryear` style meets almost all of your four requirements. And can be easily customized to meet number 2 with https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10686/105447. For a quick start with biblatex: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13513/105447. But there are plenty of sources on the matter, including here on the site.

Comment: Thanks gusbrs! Do you know how to modify:
volume.Number, pp.pageX-pageY TO volume(Number): pageX-pageY ?

Comment: Probably this is what you are looking for: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81573/105447. Anyway, there is plenty of such customizations available on the site. But if there is something you can't find, you should ask a specific question, preferably providing a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)/
[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).